# Как можно удалить данные из БД по id из RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, база-данных, recyclerview

Коллеги, спасите, дедлайн уже близко. Работа встала. В `ListView` проблем в этом не было, так как в `onItemClick` передавался `id`. В `RecyclerView` такого нет, записи удаляются и соответственно id из

```
1
2
3
4
```

Превращаются в

```
1
2
4
```

Я удаляю строку данных по позиции в списке. В итоге вся логика теряется и после первого удаления удаляется элемент до выбранного. Потом два раза до выбранного и т.д

**Адаптер**

```
public class NotesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotesAdapter.AdapterHolder> {
    Cursor cursor;
    Context context;
    NotepadActivity activity;

    public class AdapterHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView time, date, text;
        CardView card;
        ImageView edit, delete;

        AdapterHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            time = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_item_time);
            date = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_item_date);
            text = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_text);
            card = (CardView)itemView;
            edit = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_edit);
            delete = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_delete);
            delete.setOnClickListener(delete_listener);
        }

        OnClickListener delete_listener = new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                initDeleteDialog(getAdapterPosition()+1);
            }
        };
    }

    NotesAdapter(Cursor cursor, Context context) {
        this.cursor = cursor;
        this.context = context;
        this.activity = (NotepadActivity)context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public AdapterHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int p2) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.note_item, viewGroup, false);
        AdapterHolder pvh = new AdapterHolder(v);
        return pvh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final AdapterHolder holder, int position) {
        cursor.moveToPosition(position);
        String date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.NOTES_DATE));
        String time = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.NOTES_TIME));
        String color = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.NOTES_COLOR));
        String text = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.NOTES_TEXT));

        holder.time.setText(time);
        holder.date.setText(date);
        holder.text.setText(text);
        holder.card.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return cursor.getCount();
    }

    public void rebuild() {
        cursor.requery();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    void initDeleteDialog(final int position) {
        AlertDialog.Builder cansel_add_note = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        cansel_add_note.setTitle("Подтверждение");
        cansel_add_note.setMessage("Удалить эту заметку?");
        cansel_add_note.setPositiveButton("ДА", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    activity.delete(position);
                }
        });
        cansel_add_note.setNegativeButton("НЕТ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
        });
        AlertDialog cansel = cansel_add_note.create();
        cansel.show();
    }
}
```

Метод `delete` в активности

```
void delete(int position){
    database.delete(Database.NOTES_TABLE, BaseColumns._ID +"=?", new String[]{Integer.toString(position)});
    notes_adapter.rebuild();
}
```

Comment: что насчет кода? его предлагается написать отвечающему? вообще адаптер может получить id записи в текущей позиции, так как курсор находится именно в ней. что дальше делать с этой информацией решать вам, так как никаких даже намеков на реализацию адаптера в вопросе нет. И вообще ничего не понятно, что с последствиями и в чем собственно проблема

Comment: Обновил вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста, в этой теме вы шарите, помогите ещё раз со списком :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ID записей в БД и позиции в списке **никак не связаны** и работать с базой данных по позициям ни к чему хорошему в итоге не приведет. Вам нужно получать именно ID удаляемой из БД записи и работать с ним (только основные части вашего адаптера и где были изменения):

```
public class NotesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotesAdapter.AdapterHolder> {
    Cursor cursor;
    Context context;
    NotepadActivity activity;

    public class AdapterHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView time, date, text;
        CardView card;
        ImageView edit, delete;

        AdapterHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            time = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_item_time);
            date = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_item_date);
            text = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_text);
            card = (CardView)itemView;
            edit = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_edit);
            delete = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_delete);
        }
    }

    NotesAdapter(Cursor cursor, Context context) {
        this.cursor = cursor;
        this.context = context;
        this.activity = (NotepadActivity)context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final AdapterHolder holder, int position) {
        cursor.moveToPosition(position);
        Long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID));
        String date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.NOTES_DATE));
        String time = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.NOTES_TIME));
        String color = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.NOTES_COLOR));
        String text = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.NOTES_TEXT));

        holder.time.setText(time);
        holder.date.setText(date);
        holder.text.setText(text);
        holder.card.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color));
        holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
            initDeleteDialog(id);
          }
        });
    }
}
```

Я бы вообще передавал полученный ID через колбэк в активити и там уже выводил диалог удаления, вносил изменения в БД и обновлял адаптер.

Comment: @СергейГрушин Так же я вот заметил у вас в коде `cursor.moveToPosition(position);` - это лишнее, адаптер сам итерирует курсор (должен итерировать, насколько я помню)

Answer (score 0):

Включил мозги и сделал так

1) Создал метод, который создаёт/пересоздает лист из id-шников
2) В качестве id удаляемой записи передаю id из этого листа по позиции
3) После удаления пересоздаю этот лист

Comment: Это слишком сложно, ресурсоемко и не эффективно. Ни к чему хранить все айдишники, а потом еще и держать их в актуальном состоянии - ID удаляемой записи можно получить прямо из курсора в момент нажатия на кнопку удаления.