# recyclerview database delete

Tags: android, база-данных, recyclerview

Имеется `recyclerview` при нажатии на него выводится диалоговое окно, открыть, редактировать и удалить, при нажатии удалить удаляется но при перезапуске приложения все возвращается, знаю что нужно удалить выбранный `recyclerview` из баз данных,как это реализовать?

```
public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "_database";

private static final String GROUPS_TABLE_NAME = "groups_table";

public static final String GROUP_ID = "group_id";
public static final String GROUP_NAME = "group_name";
public static final String GROUP_NOTES = "group_notes";
public static final String GROUP_NOTES1 = "group_notes";
public static final String GROUP_NOTES2 = "group_notes";
public static final String GROUP_NOTES3 = "group_notes";
public static final String GROUP_NOTES4 = "group_notes";
public static final String GROUP_NOTES5 = "group_notes";
public static final String GROUP_NOTES6 = "group_notes";
public static final String GROUP_NOTES7 = "group_notes";
public static final String GROUP_NOTES8 = "group_notes";
private static final String CREATE_GROUPS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + GROUPS_TABLE_NAME + " ( " + GROUP_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
        + GROUP_NAME + " TEXT," + GROUP_NOTES + " TEXT," + GROUP_NOTES1 + " TEXT,"+GROUP_NOTES2+ " TEXT,"+
GROUP_NOTES3 + " TEXT,"
+GROUP_NOTES4 + " TEXT,"
+GROUP_NOTES5 + " TEXT,"
+GROUP_NOTES6 + " TEXT,"
+GROUP_NOTES7 + " TEXT,"
+GROUP_NOTES8 + " TEXT );";
private SQLiteDatabase database;
public MyDatabase(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_GROUPS_TABLE);
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + GROUPS_TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
public void setGroupData(String groupName, String groupNotes,String A1, String A2,String A3, String A4,String A5, String A6,String A7, String A8) {
    database = getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(GROUP_NAME, groupName);
    cv.put(GROUP_NOTES, groupNotes);
    cv.put(GROUP_NOTES1, A1);
    cv.put(GROUP_NOTES2, A2);
    cv.put(GROUP_NOTES3, A3);
    cv.put(GROUP_NOTES4, A4);
    cv.put(GROUP_NOTES5, A5);
    cv.put(GROUP_NOTES6, A6);
    cv.put(GROUP_NOTES7, A7);
    cv.put(GROUP_NOTES8, A8);
    database.insert(GROUPS_TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
}


public Cursor getGroupData() {
    database = getReadableDatabase();
    String[] columns = {GROUP_ID, GROUP_NAME, GROUP_NOTES,GROUP_NOTES1,GROUP_NOTES2,GROUP_NOTES3,GROUP_NOTES4,GROUP_NOTES5,GROUP_NOTES6,GROUP_NOTES7,GROUP_NOTES8};
    String[] columns1 = {GROUP_NOTES1,GROUP_NOTES2,GROUP_NOTES3,GROUP_NOTES4,GROUP_NOTES5,GROUP_NOTES6,GROUP_NOTES7,GROUP_NOTES8};
    Cursor c = database.query(GROUPS_TABLE_NAME, columns ,null, null, null, null, GROUP_ID + " DESC");
    return c;
}

public Cursor getGroupName(String[] args) {
    database = getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT " + GROUP_NAME + " FROM " + GROUPS_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + GROUP_NAME + " =?";
    Cursor c = database.rawQuery(query, args);
    return c;
}
}


public class MainRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MainRecyclerViewAdapter.MyMainViewHolder> {

static Context context;

int groupNameTextView, groupNotesTextView,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8;

private List<Information> mainInfo;
MyDatabase myDatabase;

private Boolean check=false;

public MainRecyclerViewAdapter(List<Information> mainInfo) {
    this.mainInfo = mainInfo;
}


public class MyMainViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView groupNameTextView, groupNotesTextView,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8;
    ImageView groupImgFull;
    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    public MyMainViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
        groupNameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.group_name_TextView);
        groupNotesTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.group_notes_TextView);
        a1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.a1);
        a2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.a2);
        a3 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.a3);
        a4 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.a4);
        a5 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.a5);
        a6 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.a6);
        a7 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.a7);
        a8 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.a8);
        groupImgFull = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.group_Img_Full);
    }

}



@Override
public MainRecyclerViewAdapter.MyMainViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                     int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.main_single_raw, parent, false);

    final MainRecyclerViewAdapter.MyMainViewHolder  myViewHolder = new MainRecyclerViewAdapter.MyMainViewHolder (view);
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!check)
            {
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    });

    return myViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyMainViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.groupNameTextView.setText(mainInfo.get(position).getGROUP_NAME());
    holder.groupNotesTextView.setText(mainInfo.get(position).getGROUP_NOTES());

    holder.a1.setText(mainInfo.get(position).getGROUP_NOTES1());
    holder.a8.setText(mainInfo.get(position).getGROUP_NOTES8());

    holder.groupImgFull.setImageResource(mainInfo.get(position).getGROUP_FULL_ICON_ID());
    holder.linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(final View v) {

                    final String converter[] ={"Открыть",
                            "Редактировать",
                            "Удалить"};
                    View convertView = (View) LayoutInflater.from(v.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.razdel_activity_main, null,true);
                    final ListView lv = (ListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lv);
                    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(v.getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,converter);
                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                    final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
                    alertDialog.setView(convertView);
                    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.a);
                    alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
                    final AlertDialog alert = alertDialog.create();
                    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
                    {
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, final long id)
                        {
                            switch ((int) id)
                            {
                                case 0:
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), DictionaryMainActivityBook.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("a1", 1);
                                    intent.putExtra("a2",String.valueOf(a2));
                                    intent.putExtra("a3",String.valueOf(a3));
                                    intent.putExtra("a4",String.valueOf(a4));
                                    intent.putExtra("a5",String.valueOf(a5));
                                    intent.putExtra("a6",String.valueOf(a6));
                                    intent.putExtra("a7",String.valueOf(a7));
                                    intent.putExtra("a8",String.valueOf(a8));
                                    v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                                    break;
                                case 1:
                                    alert.dismiss();
                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                    mainInfo.remove(position);
                                    notifyItemRemoved(position);
                                    notifyItemRangeChanged(position,mainInfo.size());
                                    alert.dismiss();
                                    break;
                                default:
                            }
                        }
                    });
            alert.show();
        }
    });

}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mainInfo.size();
}
}
```

Comment: работать в адаптере нужно непосредственно с курсором, а не каким то листом. При удалении, из курсора получать ID удаляемой записи и по нему удалять запись из БД, потом обновлять адаптер

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/611425/177345